# A shorted to ground compressor can't be a pre-existing condition can it?

Tags: grounding

Our home warranty company is trying to deny our a/c claim because the technician they sent said, our compressor was 'shorted to ground.' They say that this was a pre-existing condition and that because of that, they will not provide full payment to correct the issue.

We have only had the home for a year and the home passed the purchase inspection. We expressed this to the warranty company and their response was that ' yeah, they couldn't have seen this'.  Which I completely understand because the short occurs inside the compressor, correct?

My question is it how could this be a pre-existing condition? It only became a 'condition' once the wire grounded... a grounded wire either is grounded or it is not grounded, there is no pre to it, right?

Comment: Was it inspected in the dead of winter?  Did they not have an opportunity to run the A/C?  Did the A/C work properly when you first bought the house?

Comment: no, it was tested in springtime in Texas. As I remember it was in the '80s when they were doing the testing. It has run for over a year since with no problems.

Comment: Sounds like the home warranty company is trying to rip you off.

Comment: If it's actually "shorted to ground" which I suppose means that internally there is a short from one of the power leads to the ground should show up as an immediate circuit breaker trip whenever the unit is energized.  That would be very difficult to miss in even the most cursory inspection.  I'd push back on them as hard as needed to get them to honor the contract.  In most cases any "pre-existing" condition would need to be itemized as an "exclusion" of coverage in the warranty contact.  I'm assuming that no such exclusion exists.

Comment: I would guess that they are saying a compressor doesn't get into that failure mode without some pre-existing condition like being low on refrigerant or having a failed capacitor, etc (not sure, just making up examples).  The short is obviously not preexisting and its crazy to suggest that, so they probably are not communicating very well.  They are purposely vague to hide some of their claim practices so you might have to push for a better, more technical explanation.

Comment: I think of a "pre-existing condition" as something that you knew about and didn't tell the insurance carrier about (else they would have raised the rates or excluded coverage). Something that you didn't know about and that the inspection didn't reveal (e.g., a failing component deep in the A/C) is precisely why you buy insurance.

Comment: Did you get a acceptable insurance or was it the same as I have experienced with State Farm and left them for non payment, just asking ?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Harper they are trying to rip you off . The unit worked when you purchased the home now a year later? They say there was a pre existing condition, I say BS! Compressor  oil can go acidic in a very short time, infact a brand new compressor installed in an acidic system that was not properly flushed and new filter dryer added can short to ground in just a few days.  What causes systems to short to ground? The leading cause is moisture getting in the system and mixing with the oil, once there is moisture in the oil it will go acidic and start etching the insulation off the wires once the insulation is gone they short to ground.  There is no way to say this was pre existing it probably happened from sitting all winter. I would fight them on this especially since you have had the home for a year, if it happened within a month I could see them calling it preexisting. Call another hvac company and get there opinion, (I do have a universal 608 hvacr license and a 609 Mvac so this is not an uninformed opinion).

Comment: That's great information, very detailed and easy to understand, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How did you discover that there was something wrong with the A/C? I would assume that it stopped working in some rather obvious manner. To my way of thinking this is a textbook example of "not a pre-existing condition."

A short to ground should trip a breaker as soon as the compressor is energized. This is most definitely something that the inspection could have uncovered - A/C and/or heat not working. Since you've been in the house for a year, and you ran the A/C last summer the insurance company seems to be on very thin ice.

I think you should taking stock of the situation:

- Start off by reading the warranty carefully - with an eye to how they define "pre-existing condition" and what they take responsibility for when they write your warranty.
- Next take a look at your home inspection report - does it mention the A/C one way or the other?
- Finally take stock of what evidence you have that it ever worked during your ownership of the home (do your utility bills reflect running the A/C last summer?).

If the overall picture suggests that you're in the right, they lay out your case to the insurance company. If they turn you down get some estimates on the repair and start looking into your state's small claims process. In many states it is a pretty simple and inexpensive process.

Comment: Yes, the home inspection did a  thorough inspection of the units, checking even the freon levels and air temps at every register. 

Their "pre-existing condition" clause is somewhat vague and boils down to a 'noticeable flaw or defect that can be reasonably discovered via routine inspection.'

Comment: If they checked the Freon levels they have opened the system and could have introduced a leak that caused the problem, since the levels were fine at The acceptance with this information I would say you have a case and would contact the better business bureau and file a claim. I would also contact a lawyer but remember they can eat up any award unless you are in a state that allows legal fees to be covered, in my state we have to wait 6 months from the date of the loss to be able to recover legal fees on property issues. But with the fact they checked the system it was fine when you signed.

Comment: Small claims court may be the way to go. Costs are very low and, at least in Washington, lawyers are not allowed.